# C: error C2105: '++' needs lvalue

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros

Windows, MSVS 2010.

I am unable to understand why this is generating compilation error:

```
#define INC(X) X++

int main() {

    int X; 
    printf("%d", INC(X++)); 

    return 0; 

}
```

**Error:**

> Error 1   error C2105: '++' needs
>   l-value   testing.cpp 19  1   testing

Answer (score 9):

The result of expanding the macro would be `X++++`.

The postfix `++` operator increments the value of the variable and returns the value before the incrementation. It's does not return an lvalue (a variable) - just a value. You can't apply `++` to it just like you can't call `3++`.

Answer (score 5):

A macro definition like

```
INC(X++)
```

is same as

```
X++++
```

which is, (as per the greedy compiler rule) `(X++)++`.

Remember, `#define` MACROs are not function calls, rather they are textual replacements happening at the preprocessing phase, so, in essence, your code looks like `(5++)++` which is invalid, as increment / decerement operator can be used on variables [`lvalue`], not on a value itself (non-lvalue).

Note: You can increment the *value* held by a variable. You cannot increment a value itself.
Here, `X` is not a variable. As a part of the MACRO expansion, it's substituted with `5` at preprocessing time.

To summarize, you cannot do something like `5++`, it's like increment `5` by `1` and store it into `5`.

Answer (score 4):

```
INC(X++)
```

expands to

```
X++++
```

That is to say,

```
(X++)++
```

...and `X++` is not an lvalue, so it can't be incremented.